# Awk script to find, match and copy value in two file basis on some condition

Tags: linux, shell, awk, scripting

Need your help to write code in awk for below query.
Have two file.
If value in column1(documenttype) is INV and supplytype(column2) is CAN, then take out corresponding value from column3(documentnumber),
and find that value(documentnumber) in file2 in column2(follon doc) and if found, then fetch the values of column1(predecessr) from file2 present against that documentnumber(follon doc) and paste that value found from column1(predecesssr) from file2 in column4(originaldocumentnumber) in file1

For ex-

if we have documentnumber 420075416 with documenttype as INV and supplytype as CAN in file1, then we can see documentnumber(420075416) is present in file2 in row4 and column2(follon doc), so then pick value(430071501) against that documentnumber(420075416) from column1(predecessr) if available in file2 and replace or paste in column4 of file1

File1

```
documenttype    supplytype  documentnumber  originaldocumentnumber
INV              CAN        420075416        656565665
INV              CAN        429842808   
INV              BRB        429842808         85858585
INV              CAN        430071605   
RER              CAN        430071609
```

File2

```
Predecessr  FollOn doc
420075200   430071605
429842808   430071609
429842807   429842808
430071501   420075416
429842807   429842808
```

output file

```
documenttype    supplytype  documentnumber  originaldocumentnumber
INV              CAN       420075416            430071501
INV              CAN       429842808            429842807
INV              BRB       429842808            85858585
INV              CAN       430071605            420075200
RER              CAN       430071609
```

Able to write below piece code only, but got confused so not able to proceed further

```
if '(NR==FNR)&&(FNR>1)&&($1==INV && $2==CAN){ar[$3]=NR;next}
    {for(i in ar){if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apart from eye-candy spacing this should do the trick:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                              # process first file
    a[$2]=$1                           # hash, 2nd column as key, 1st its value
    next                               # next record
}                                      # second file:
$1=="INV" && $2=="CAN" && ($3 in a) {  # INV, CAN and 3rd column in hash
    $4=a[$3]                           # set 4th column value from the hash
    # flag=1                           # see comment
}
{
    $1=$1                              # rebuild the record 
    print                              # output
}
#END {
#    if(!flag) 
#        system("cat " FILENAME)
# }
' file2 file1                         # mind the order
documenttype supplytype documentnumber originaldocumentnumber
INV CAN 420075416 430071501
INV CAN 429842808 429842807
INV BRB 429842808 85858585
INV CAN 430071605 420075200
RER CAN 430071609
```

You could pipe that to `column -t` to make it look nicer:

```
$ awk ... | column -t 
documenttype  supplytype  documentnumber  originaldocumentnumber
INV           CAN         420075416       430071501
...
```

Comment: ...thank you for the solution..could you please explain the above code as how it is working

Comment: I have one more query..where i have three tables and after comapring and mapping data from these table needs to put in one table

Comment: Added comments to the code. Regarding the three table problem, post a new question as you need to post samples and better definition anyway.

Comment: Hi James Brown..If there is no record of type INV in column1 and type CAN in column2 in FIle1..then need to print the output of File1 as it is in new file and if found record then need to print the output in new file with changes as what you did in your above code..please let me know how to handle this part..
Note : need to make only one new output file for both the cases

Comment: If I understood you right: set a flag inside the INV and CAN block (insert `flag=1` before or after `$4=a[$3]`) and make an `END` block: `END{if(!flag) system("cat " FILENAME)}`. If there is no INV + CAN record, flag stays down and in the `END` the whole `file1` is outputed.

Comment: Thanks James..will execute this and let you know the output

Comment: Hi James Brown..i have tried the updated solution and it worked but it is printing File1 data twice in the new output file..so i am getting same record twice. Can you please help..and can you please let me know how this statement is helping is "system("cat " FILENAME)"

Comment: what filename should come for "FILENAME" or it can be any name

Comment: `system("cat " FILENAME)` uses `cat` to print the current file in variable `FILENAME`, being `file1` at that point.